# Kubuntu screen magnifier doesn't follow the cursor

Tags: kubuntu, accessibility, zooming

I'm a sight impaired and use Kubuntu. I'm really happy with it but have a little problem.  When I write a document or an e-mail,  I have to use the screen magnifier, and it doesn't follow the cursor while I write. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome, the Kubuntu screen magnifier is called `kmag`, and you can install it with the command `sudo apt install -y kmag`. But... I found it unusable, and couldn't find the way to do what you ask for. Gnome magnifier does it, and it's easy to use. Would you be willing to switch to Gnome to get get this feature? You can install it along with kde (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: _"and it doesn't follow the cursor while I write"_ - Do you mean the mouse cursor, or the text cursor that indicates where typed letters go?

Comment: @marcelm one doesn't normally "write" with the mouse, so I think it's safe to assume that text cursor is meant.

Comment: @Ruslan I'd rather ask than speculate. So far, the only answer here doesn't follow your assumption, so there's already confusion. I think it's important to clarify this part for sure, with an answer from Belén.

Answer (score 4):

There is wmagnify, which is a stationary window that displays a magnified version of where the mouse pointer is. To use it you will have to `sudo apt install wmaker` and then run `wmagnify` from the terminal.In kubuntu you can make a window a "keep above others" from the window menu which is useful for wmagnify.Ubuntu man page for wmagnify [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/wmagnify.1.html) but basically keys 1-9 change the magnification. The window updates regularly (adjustable rate) so if you magnify something that is changing you will still see it, eg if you hover the mouse over the clock, it will update.

Edit: I should add there is also xzoom which is similar and I think is installed by default, but I find it inferior to wmagnify.

Comment: Also, not related directly to your question, but if you are using a "light" theme because they are easier to read than the "dark" themes (for me anyway") it is worth trying a red cursor/mouse pointer if you have not already.

Comment: I've just installed on Kubuntu 20.04 and it kept zooming indefinitely...

Comment: It seems the OP was talking about _text cursor_, not mouse cursor: _"When I write a document or an e-mail"_. One doesn't usually "write a document" with a mouse, so the motion of the screen magnifier focus by the mouse cursor is not useful for this purpose.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity was the mouse pointer over the wmagnify window itself? That's what happens because it magnifies the area under the mouse pointer. So the mouse pointer needs to be over another area of the screen. But I have not tried it on 20.04.

Comment: Now someone needs a way to improve the resolution of Emojis it scanned; they are kind'a important these days, and all implemented in vectors so they should infinitely scale

Answer (score 0):

We just had a discussion about this on a lug I belong to and [Magnus](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/magnus-a-simple-screen-magnifier-for-ubuntu/) was suggested. It will follow the mouse cursor.

I haven't tried it, but if you are using wmagnify as @B.Tanner suggests and you happen to have access to a second monitor, you might be able to have the magnified version display on the second monitor instead of covering up part of your main display. (Try dragging the wmagnify window to the second display which is set to "appear" next to the original desktop in your window manager settings. You can set this up in KDE under System Settings->Display And Monitor.)

On a single display, it seems like the magnified version always ends up covering something else you need to see at the same time and this would eliminate that issue and give you more space to work with on each screen if it works.

If you do try this, it will simplify your life if the second monitor has the same screen resolution as the main monitor. Otherwise, some mouse movements will place the mouse cursor in invisible off-screen locations and it can take a bit of flailing to locate it again.

Comment: That is exactly what I do. I have a second monitor (in portrait orientation, but that is beside the point). I can confirm you can put wmagnify on either monitor and magnify either the same monitor or the other monitor (Kubuntu 18.04). In my case the monitors *do* have different resolutiuons and there are no invisible areas - the mouse is constrained to the monitor it is on. My main monitor is a 4k 13" laptop (Dell XPS 13) and the second monitor is a 1920x1200 portable monitor (Asus USB-C). Did require some xrandr magic in 18.04, I don'tknow if it can be done through Systems Settings in 20.04.